# javaCC inserts non-wanted statements

Tags: java, grammar, javacc

I've got the following **javacc** grammar.

The rule **UnaryExpr** creates some anonymous classes implementing `java.util.function.Predicate<>`

```
options {
static=false;
DEBUG_PARSER=false;
IGNORE_CASE=true;
JDK_VERSION="1.8";
}

(...)

private Predicate<SAMRecord> UnaryExpr(): { }
    {
    (
    <DUPLICATE> { return new Predicate<SAMRecord>() {
            @Override public boolean test(final SAMRecord rec) { return rec.getDuplicateReadFlag();}
        };}
    | <UNMAPPED> { return new Predicate<SAMRecord>() {
            @Override public  boolean test(final SAMRecord rec) { return rec.getReadUnmappedFlag();}
        };}
    | <FAILSVENDORQUALITY> { return new Predicate<SAMRecord>() {
            @Override public  boolean test(final SAMRecord rec) { return rec.getReadFailsVendorQualityCheckFlag();}
        };}
    | <PROPERPAIR> { return new Predicate<SAMRecord>() {
            @Override public boolean test(final SAMRecord rec) { return rec.getReadPairedFlag();}
        };}
    )
    }
```

when I'm generating the code using javacc 7.0.2, the generated java code contains some extra statements that break the code `{if ("" != null)`. In the java file, instead or my original code:

```
@Override public boolean test(final SAMRecord rec) {return rec.getDuplicateReadFlag();}
```

I've got:

```
@Override public boolean test(final SAMRecord rec) { {if ("" != null) return rec.getDuplicateReadFlag();}}
```

How can I fix this ? Thanks .

Comment: cross-posted: https://github.com/javacc/javacc/issues/24

Answer (score 1):

That's a rather annoying behaviour.

Could you live with this?

```
private Predicate<SAMRecord> UnaryExpr(): {
    class A implements Predicate<SAMRecord> {
        @Override public boolean test(final SAMRecord rec) {
            return rec.getDuplicateReadFlag(); } }

    class B implements Predicate<SAMRecord> {
        @Override public boolean test(final SAMRecord rec) {
            return rec.getReadUnmappedFlag(); } }

    class C implements Predicate<SAMRecord> {
        @Override public boolean test(final SAMRecord rec) {
            return rec.getReadFailsVendorQualityCheckFlag(); } }

    class D implements Predicate<SAMRecord> {
        @Override public boolean test(final SAMRecord rec) {
            return rec.getReadPairedFlag(); } }
}
{
    ( <DUPLICATE> { return new A() ; }
    | <UNMAPPED> { return new B() ; }
    | <FAILSVENDORQUALITY> { return new C() ; }
    | <PROPERPAIR> { return new D() ; }
    )
}
```

Comment: yes , that was my idea than, for I've created a some static methods in the parser  to generate my instances `static Predicate<SAMRecord> createA(); static Predicate<SAMRecord> createB();`

Comment: Right.  That works too.  There's no need for the classes to be nonstatic.  In fact there is probably no need to create a new object each time.